# How to add ellipses text overflowing of value in kendo combobox?

Tags: css, kendo-ui, kendo-combobox

Currently, I have a few kendo Comboboxes in one line on my page and I am using MVVM to bind values to it. Each Combobox has the same template:

```
<input data-role="combobox"
    data-auto-bind="false"
    data-text-field="ContactName"
    data-value-field="Id"
    data-value-primitive="true"
    data-placeholder="Select Contact"
    data-bind="value: @valueBinding, source: myContacts, events: { change: onChange }"
    style="width:100%" />
```

As far as page can be opened on mobile devices, I should support text-overflow ellipses, to show for example "The first..." instead of "The first item".

I tried next solutions:

1) Just add css style for inputs:

```
.k-combobox .k-input {
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

This Solution is working only during resizing but not after page is opened.

2) Add new css class ellipses-input

```
input.ellipses-input{
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

After data were loaded to comboboxes(using ajax request and kendo.bind) I use next jQuery code:

```
$(".my-container input").addClass("ellipses-input");
```

Here ".my-container" is just a div wrapper on comboboxes.

Are there any way to solve this problem just using CSS without jQuery?

Comment: Does adding !important to your CSS make a difference? .k-combobox .k-input { text-overflow: ellipsis !important; }

Comment: Ezanker, thank you for response! Unfortunately "!important" don't make any influence

Comment: Why didn't you place the `ellipses-input` class on the `<input>` elements in the template?

Comment: Tried so many solutions, but not able to get any workaround, did you guys mange to get it working ?